# Previous employer is asking to be paid to write a reference?

Tags: communication, references, asia

I have asked a previous employer to write a reference for me. They have come back to me asking that they be paid for it, stating that it is:

> work

I find this highly unusual and completely inappropriate.

Is this normal, or even accepted, behavior?

Some additional details:

- Education sector
- Asia
- Boss, individually demanding reimbursement, certainly no paper trail

Comment: What do you mean by "employer" here..your boss (individually) or the organization?

Comment: Please add an indication of your location and industry; this sort of thing can vary immensely.

Comment: Please add a location tag. Your answer will range from "they are legally required to do it for free" over "they should really do it for free it's professional courtesy" to "damn right they want money for it". And if you don't add a location tag, you will never know which of them applies to you.

Comment: "reimbursement" - for what? the time taken to write a recommendation? If not anything, this is silly. :)

Comment: Also, please make it clear whether the boss wants to be paid a) personally under the table, b) personally with an invoice, c) as part of their job and you will get the invoice from the company d) has some kind of official table (i.e. any reference is amount X handling fee and Y postage as per the official company table for correspondence)

Comment: This sounds to me like your boss is saying "No" without actually saying "No".

Comment: @nvoigt The closest is probably A; I think it's just a case of being petty and wanting to money for, supposed, "work."

Comment: @SouravGhosh Where in the world would such a practice be acceptable? Where would "damn right they want money for it" actually apply?

Comment: @teego1967 I don't think I told that. :)

Comment: I would contact HR in that company to ask about the rates to pay for a reference and give them the details... it won’t get you a reference from him though but I think the value of a reference from that boss it should be written on toilet paper.

Comment: @Mou某 I think location may need to be more specific.  I've worked in Asia and never heard of it but it could be the norm in a specific country.  Most advice on here will be US/Western Europe based so I would make sure the answers you get are specific to your situation and that the person giving the answer is speaking from a place of knowledge of that culture.

Comment: @Myles To clarify, I'm from India and I've worked with organizations all over APAC, never heard / experienced incidents like this, for over a decade and then some.

Comment: how much did they ask ?!!?!?

Comment: @Myles, where would something like this "be the norm?"

Comment: @teego1967 Nowhere that I know but I acknowledge that there are places for which I am unaware of workplace customs.  Asia is home to a lot of different cultures with widely different norms.  It's like asking if apple based sauce goes on a noodle dish in European cooking.  There are enough different cuisine's out there that it's unlikely anyone could say definitively no rather than probably not.

Comment: I had two coworkers from various countries shared stories about paying to get an interview to a company, paying to get your holidays choice before another coworker, etc. This seems to happen on sub of some countries where employer have a lot of candidates and power. We just felt lucky where we live after hearing those stories.

Comment: Did he give a price? Sounds like a joke, or implying he'd need to be paid to say anything good about you. I once told a guy I wouldn't reference him for a job cleaning toilets.

Answer (score 12):

### No.

Under no circumstances, references / recommendations should be paid (for). Above everything, it's unethical (if not illegal), as when payment is involved, things are sure to be biased.

Find someone else, who will be ready to pen down a couple of good lines for you, because you did something good actually, not because you are ready to pay.

*P.S.- The fact that there's no paper trail for the demanded transaction, this is definitely not invoiceable, making the intention far form fair.*

Comment: While I'm fully with you that it would be completely unethical - if the former employer  would keep insisting and that reference is of uttermost importance  - why not grease that engine with a bit of oil - obviously depending on the quality of the recommendation and the amount of oil needed..

Comment: @iLuvLogix maybe, but then, in case this guy has done the same with others, and for some reason this is exposed, based on the size of the industry, it can have a negative effect that OP actually had a reference / recommendation from that guy. I'd leave that guy out of my resume / reference list if I were OP.